# In episode 46 of Dragon Ball Super, why are destroyers 1, 5 and 8 still there?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

In episode 46 of *Dragon Ball Super*, only two universes remain. Yet in the beginning, when all the crowd is put closer, one can clearly see 3 extra destroyers.

[image: the 3 destroyers]

Why are they still there? Also, there are missing 'angels'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gods of destruction of those universes didnt participate in the tournament. They didnt participate because they had a high mortal level determined by Zeno.

According to

[Mortal level](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Mortal_Level)

> All the universes with Mortal Level lower than 7 were planned to be erased, but after the suggestion of Goku to perform the Tournament of Power, they were given a chance to avoid erasure by winning

Meaning the other universes were safe and didnt participate in the tournament of power, and the gods of destruction of those universes either, and they could just sit and watch the tournament